# Is there a way to get Slack's focused channel name programmatically in macOS/Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, applescript, slack

Is there a way that macOS/Swift app can retrieve Slack's currently-focused Workspace name and channel name?

So, given that Slack app is running, is there any way my 3rd-party-app can inspect Slack's app UI elements or directly get a name of currently focused Workspace and channel name?

I had a look at [Slack-Applescript github project](https://github.com/samknight/slack_applescript), but it doesn't support retrieval of relevant data.

Comment: This can be done via AppleScript. If you get the name of the front window of the process Slack using System Events, you'll notice that the selected channel or person is part of the window name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user3579815 posted in its comment, Slack Window name contains the relevant data I requested in the question.